# Regex to match parmaters of function

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text on my page:

```
pageTracker._addItem("2040504","JACQXSPINKASS-TX4-8","Jacq Socks","","9.00000","1.0");
pageTracker._addItem("2040504","FTWCLSNOCOLOURONE SIZE","Footwear Cleaner","","8.00000","1.0");
```

I would like to just extract the parameters that are within the brackets for each line using javascripts `match()` function. I have the following regex but it's not quite right:

```
/\b_addItem[^);]+/g
```

This matches the `_addItem(` part as well. How can I tweak this to only get the stuff inside the brackets?

[Regexr example](http://regexr.com/3e9uq)

Ideally it should match any string that begins with `pageTracker._addItem("` but not include that part in the match up to the closing bracket.

I am going to be doing the matching with javascript with I don't think supports look behinds if I'm right

Answer (score 1):

Use a *look behind* to assert, but not capture, the preceding text:

```
/(?<=pageTracker\._addItem\()[^);]+/g
```

Note that I added `(` to the look behind to not capture that either.

---

Now that you've added the JavaScript tag, where look behinds are not supported, you must capture your target in a group:

```
/pageTracker\._addItem\(([^);]+)/g
```

Your target will be in group 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into two regular expression calls to avoid look-behind:

```
var str = 'pageTracker._addItem("2040504","JACQXSPINKASS-TX4-8","Jacq Socks","","9.00000","1.0");\npageTracker._addItem("2040504","FTWCLSNOCOLOURONE SIZE","Footwear Cleaner","","8.00000","1.0");'
var m,output=[];
var re = /^pageTracker._addItem\("(.*)"\)/gm;
while(m=re.exec(str)) 
  output.push(m[1].split('","'));
```

Output is then a 2D array:

```
[ 
  ["2040504","JACQXSPINKASS-TX4-8","Jacq Socks","","9.00000","1.0"],
  ["2040504","FTWCLSNOCOLOURONE SIZE","Footwear Cleaner","","8.00000","1.0"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows too

```js
var strings = ['pageTracker._addItem("2040504","JACQXSPINKASS-TX4-8","Jacq Socks","","9.00000","1.0");',
               'pageTracker._addItem("2040504","FTWCLSNOCOLOURONE SIZE","Footwear Cleaner","","8.00000","1.0");'
              ],
       args = strings.map(s => s.match(/".*?"/g)
                                .map(s => s.replace(/"/g,'')));
console.log(args);
```